# Azure function requesting same message multiple times on service bus queue

Tags: azure-functions, azure-servicebus-topics

I'm trying to write a single message to service bus topic using the http trigger azure function in visual studio. I found that when I run the code locally that it will send through my message multiple times even though when I step through the code, it only hits the code once.
Obviously, I only wanted to hit the topic once and not multiple times. Are there any particular reason it is happening with the below code
Here is my code

```
        ServiceBusClient client = new ServiceBusClient(servicebusconn);
        ServiceBusSender sender = client.CreateSender(queuename);
        ServiceBusMessage message = new ServiceBusMessage("a");
        try
        {
            await sender.SendMessageAsync(message);
        }
        finally
        {

            await sender.DisposeAsync();
            await client.DisposeAsync();
        }
```

[image: service bus topic]

Comment: After Reproducing the program you have given it checks out and  it is working in the expected manner.  I think every time you peek the messages through the portal  it is increasing the number of request.

Comment: From the screenshot you've attached, there is only one message, are you talking about the number of requests ?